# Cadastro em php

Tags: php, mysql

Ola, tudo bom ?, estou com um problema em realizar inserção de dados em um banco de dados MYSQL. Quando digito uma senha no meu formulario, por exemplo: metas123, ou uma outra senha qualquer, ele armazena o valor 0, em vez da string digitada, e realmente não faço a mínima ideia do porque isso acontecer... se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito.

```
if (!empty($_POST['user']) and !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

     $g_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user']);
     $g_pass = $_POST['pass'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha) VALUES ('$g_user', '$g_pass');";
     $executa = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     switch ($executa) {

       case true:
         header("Location: login_page/index.php?cadastro=sucesso");
         break;

       default:
         header("Location: index.php?cadastro=erro");
         break;

      }
   }
```

*Código de inserção ao banco de dados mysql

Comment: obrigado kk, primeira vez que eu mexo no stackoverflow, desculpa qualquer coisa

Comment: Essa pergunta só poderia ser respondida se vc colocasse os tipos de colunas da sua tabela e os tipos de como estão sendo enviados .

Comment: Quais os valores que vem do `$_POST` ? Eles estão corretos ? Teste com `var_dump($_POST);` e confirme se tem os valores corretos. Depois faça o que o Leo disse e coloque a estrutura da tabela `usuarios`  na pergunta para termos a certeza que os tipos são os corretos.

Comment: opa, tudo bom isac?, admiro sua atenção, mas felizmente ja resolvi o problema, o tipo do campo na tabela senha estava marcado como INT.

Answer (score -1):

Tem um `;` sobrando ali:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha) VALUES ('$g_user', '$g_pass');";
```

Substitua por:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha) VALUES ('$g_user', '$g_pass')";
```

**[RESOLVIDO] Tipo do campo na tabela estava incorreto**

Comment: vou tentar aqui

Comment: ah ja identifiquei o problema.. obrigado, eu marquei o campo senha como int kkkkk, mas obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Show, eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar!